# How can I make live updates of text to my app

Tags: ios, auto-update

Well.. It´s hard to explain my question, but I try!
In the app I am making, I have to be able to update the text inside it regularly from my home computer. So people can push refresh and get the updated text. How can this be done the best way? 
-----------------------------------------------EDIT---------   I have an dropbox account I would use. I have tried with this code: NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString: @"dropbox.com/s/6660fyhyfn3n3kg/text.plist"]; NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path]; self.text = [dict objectForKey:@"text1"]; It is labels and textviews that needs to be updated, mostly labels. I tried using a plist that I have in Dropbox. So I want the application to load the plist from dropbox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Basic web server hosting is dirt cheap (often free).  Upload your text files to a web server and then have the app request those text files.  With Cocoa, you can use an NSURLConnection to retrieve such resources.

I recommend structuring the text files (e.g. XML) as it'll be easy to add metadata.  If you have large amounts of text, then you should probably post them as individual files plus an index file.  The index file would indicate the time of the most recent updates for each individual text file.  Then you only need to request the index and the text files that are newer.

Comment: I have an dropbox account I would use.
I have tried with this code: 

 NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.dropbox.com/s/6660fyhyfn3n3kg/text.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path];

    self.text = [dict objectForKey:@"text1"];                           It is labels and textviews that needs to be updated, mostly labels. I tried using a plist that I have in Dropbox. So I want the application to load the plist from dropbox. Any ideas?